# Difference between SUM(CASE...) and CASE WHEN ... THEN SUM(...)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I came across expression (Postgres):

```
SELECT
  ...,
  CASE WHEN colXX in (...) THEN sum(colYY) END
FROM tbl
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ..., colXX;
```

It blew my mind. OK, it has sense if there is `GROUP BY` for `CASE WHEN`.

Can anyone confirm that using aggregation inside of `CASE WHEN` is some proprietary SQL extension?

I usually use such form:

```
SELECT
  ...,
  sum(CASE WHEN colXX in (...) THEN colYY END)
FROM tbl ...;
```

which works even if `colXX` isn't in `GROUP BY` and it has clear semantic.

Also PostgreSQL and HSQLDB has fancy syntax for previous form:

```
SELECT
  ...,
  sum(colYY) FILTER (WHERE colXX in (...))
FROM tbl ...;
```

So my question is: which standard or proprietary extensions define aggregation inside `CASE` and what is the semantic of such expression and what restrictions are in affect when such construction is used?

Answer (score 2):

All three of your syntaxes are ISO/ANSI standard.  The third, using `filter` is only available in a small number of databases (Postgres, the most recent version of SQLite, and some others).

These do exactly the same thing:

```
sum(colYY) FILTER (WHERE colXX in (...))
sum(CASE WHEN colXX in (...) THEN colYY END)
```

They sum `colYY` on rows where the condition is met.  These require that no mentioned columns (neither `colXX` nor `colYY`) be in the `GROUP BY` clause.  In fact, these would normally *not* be used if either were in the `GROUP BY`.

This:

```
(CASE WHEN colXX in (...) THEN sum(colYY) END)
```

is quite different.  It requires that `colXX` be in the `GROUP BY`.  It will calculate the sum on any rows where the `colXX` condition is true.  Other rows will have a value of `NULL`.  In my experience, this version is less commonly needed then the other two.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0489abcbf1aa4db4523d56ae3db314da) is a db<>fiddle that illustrates what is happening.

Comment: By saying "standard" you mean it is described by one of SQL standard?

Comment: @gavenkoa . . . Yes.  But being standard doesn't mean that they are actually implemented in any real databases (although the versions with `case` are supported by basically all databases).

Comment: It looks like the only valid predicates for inner aggregation are `=` / `<>` / `in`. Seems it is impossible to check for `<` or complicated math expression like `col * col = 5`. Is it to be in agreement with `GROUP BY`?

Comment: As a side note: `filter` is also supported by HSQLDB (as mentioned in the question) and in the current SQLite version.

Comment: @gavenkoa . . . I don't know what you mean -- any expression should be allowed, including complex expressions using subqueries.  Perhaps you should ask another question if something you are trying is not working.